# Calculate File upload time on server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, time, server

I want to calculate how much time a particular encryption algorithm takes while uploading files on the server.

I have used `time.process_time()` , `time.time()` like function to calculate the time taken by Encryption algorithm,but they are giving inaccurate values on server.

```
start_time = time.process_time()

encryption_algo()

toatl_time = time.process_time() - start_time
```

The output on the local machine is accurate but on the server, it's not.
Ex:- if `6.00`s on local then it is like `0.444`s on a server, So how can I effectively calculate the time taken to encrypt file?

Comment: Could you please clarify your expected result? Do you mean it takes more longer on server?

Comment: On the server, it's taking so much less time than on the local machine.

Comment: Could you please try timeit module and compare the results.